# React hooks : How to implement a "slow update" counter

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-hooks, counter

I've been trying to implement some custom hook that perfom an increment but with some time delta.

The idea is the reproduce an in-game common feature when increasing the user's gold for example,  you can see the gold updating to the "real" value slowly.

But I think that I'm overkilling it and it may have an easier answer than this try :

```js
let timerId = null;
const useSlowUpdateValue = (
  value,
  MAX_TIME = 2000,
  NB_MAX_UPDATE = 80
) => {
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    console.log("Warning : useSlowUpdateValue ne s'utilise qu'avec des int !");
  }
  const UPDATE_INTERVAL = MAX_TIME / NB_MAX_UPDATE;
  const [current, setCurrent] = React.useState(value || 0);
  const previousValue = React.useRef(value || 0);
  const originValue = React.useRef(value || 0);

  const [step, setStep] = React.useState(0);
  const [delta, setDelta] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (step !== 0) {
      if (
        (step > 0 && current + step > value) ||
        (step < 0 && current + step < value)
      ) {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        setStep(0);
        setDelta(0);
        originValue.current = value;
        setCurrent(value);
      } else {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        timerId = setTimeout(
          () => setCurrent((old) => old + step),
          UPDATE_INTERVAL
        );
      }
    }
  }, [current, step, UPDATE_INTERVAL, value]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (value !== previousValue.current) {
      previousValue.current = value;
      const deltaToPrint = value - originValue.current;
      const currentDelta = value - current;
      const nextStep = currentDelta / NB_MAX_UPDATE;
      setStep(nextStep);
      setDelta(deltaToPrint);
    }
  }, [value, NB_MAX_UPDATE, current]);

  return { current: Math.round(current), delta };
};



const App = () => {
  const [gold, setGold] = React.useState(0);
  const {current, delta} = useSlowUpdateValue(gold);

const addRandomGold  = () => {
  const r  = Math.floor(Math.random() * 555);
  setGold(gold+r);
}

const substractRandomGold  = () => {
  const r  = Math.floor(Math.random() * 222);
  setGold(gold-r);
}
const redStyle = {color:"red"};
const greenStyle = {color:"green"};
  return (
    <div>
      <div>You have {gold} golds</div>
      <div>
        <div>Prettier logged like this : </div>
        <div>{current} 
          {delta !== 0 && (
            <span style={delta > 0 ? greenStyle : redStyle}>
              ({delta > 0 && "+"}{delta})
            </span>)
          }
        </div>
      </div>
      <button onClick={addRandomGold}>++ golds</button>
      <button onClick={substractRandomGold}>-- golds</button>
    </div>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

If you try playing arround with MAX_TIME you'll see that it isn't perfectly the time taken to update....

I would like to know if there's a simplest way to implement this kind of feature ? Or just improve it a bit ?

Every constructive critisims are welcome